# AWS EC2 Charging on Free Tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have enabled EC2, RDS and S3 for my spring boot application hosted on AWS. As i have selected free tier plan for those and i am really shocked that they are charging. I verified payment and can see most of the charges is for EC2 instance. I am running single instance.

Why they are charging me? How to avoid charging for the first year?

Comment: What exactly are you running for the instance, i.e. its configuration?

Comment: You still get charged for any resources that exceed the free tier limit, as well as services not included in free tier.

Comment: What instance types do you have provisioned? What size are the attached EBS volumes?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the details from your Billing Console.

Answer (score 2):

Calm down!
You can see it's charging in the `Billing Dashboard` that's right.
However, that's just a `Forecast` of your spend and at the end of the month AWS will cut zero of your money (unless you used service out of your free-tier limits)

Conclusion: The `Billing Dashboard` estimation doesn't separate between your usage if it's from your free-tier or not, it just estimates your usage, I know it looks stupid but that's how AWS Billing Dashboard works.

Note: In order to use the free tier you have to use both a free tier AMI and free tier instance types.[image: Choose Free tier only][image: free tier instance]

Update: to avoid that's from happening again read this link [Avoiding unexpected charges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/checklistforunwantedcharges.html)

Comment: No, My account was suspended due to non payment and i paid the amounts for reactivate my account.

Comment: I'm sorry for this accident :/

You may refer to the link above it's from AWS to avoid unexpected charges in the furure

Answer (score 2):

The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) is a **billing discount**. It is not a "free plan".

Each month, a certain quantity of services are included in the Free Tier. If you stay within these limits, there will be no charge.

You did not provide any details, but it seems that your usage exceeded the amounts provided under the Free Tier.

Answer (score 0):

The same was for me after all some time for example 3 weeks i haven't been using aws ec2 but it was showing a billing on the free tier.

Comment: i was using sagemaker as notebook